# exact_count not working in ansible for aws ec2 module

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

While setting up ec2 instance in AWS the exact_count parameter doesnt seem to be working, from what i understand this needs the count_tag to be present and checks it for duplicate value.

The current code is below

```
- name: Creating the EC2 instance
  tags: "ec2"
  ec2:
    key_name: "{{ key_name }}"
    image: "{{ image }}"
    assign_public_ip: "yes"
    instance_tags:
      server: ec2-1
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ public_subnet.subnet.id }}"
    region: "{{ region }}"
    zone: "ap-south-1a"
    #security_group: "{{security_group_name}}"
    exact_count: 1
    count_tag:
       Name: "ec2-1"
    instance_type: "{{instance_type}}"
    aws_access_key: "{{AWSAccessKeyId}}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ AWSSecretKey }}"
  register: "ec2"

- debug:
    var: ec2
- ec2_instance_info:
    filters:
      "tag:server": ec2-1
  register: "ec2_info"
- debug:
    var: ec2_info
```

Am i missing the concept or the code is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind! The tags key:value pair was different in definition and execution

name: Creating the EC2 instance

```
  tags: "ec2"
  ec2:
    key_name: "{{ key_name }}"
    image: "{{ image }}"
    assign_public_ip: "yes"
    instance_tags:
      server: ec2-1
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ public_subnet.subnet.id }}"
    region: "{{ region }}"
    zone: "ap-south-1a"
    #security_group: "{{security_group_name}}"
    exact_count: 1
    count_tag:
       server: "ec2-1"
    instance_type: "{{instance_type}}"
    aws_access_key: "{{AWSAccessKeyId}}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ AWSSecretKey }}"
  register: "ec2"

- debug:
    var: ec2
- ec2_instance_info:
    filters:
      "tag:server": ec2-1
  register: "ec2_info"
- debug:
    var: ec2_info
```